# What is required for windows to recognize a custom HID device?

Tags: c++, embedded, usb, stm32f4discovery, windows-kernel

Currently, I'm working with an STM32F746G-DISCO dev kit, and I'm trying to build a generic HID device.  (not keyboard, not controller, not mouse, etc.)  Using the mbed libraries, the setup was pretty simple and painless.  I was able to import their USBHID.h and declare a device.

```
USBHID(descriptor.output_report_length, descriptor.input_report_length, descriptor.vendor_id, descriptor.product_id, descriptor.product_release, descriptor.connect)
```

Given values defined by the defaults in this descriptor structure I created:

```
{
    this->output_report_length = 64;
    this->input_report_length = 64;
    this->vendor_id = 0x1234;
    this->product_id = 0x500;
    this->product_release = 0x0001;
    this->connect = true;
}
```

All of this creates a USB HID report description in USBHID.cpp (mbed's library):

```
uint8_t * USBHID::reportDesc() {
static uint8_t reportDescriptor[] = {
    0x06, LSB(0xFFAB), MSB(0xFFAB),
    0x0A, LSB(0x0200), MSB(0x0200),
    0xA1, 0x01,         // Collection 0x01
    0x75, 0x08,         // report size = 8 bits
    0x15, 0x00,         // logical minimum = 0
    0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,   // logical maximum = 255
    0x95, input_length, // report count
    0x09, 0x01,         // usage
    0x81, 0x02,         // Input (array)
    0x95, output_length,// report count
    0x09, 0x02,         // usage
    0x91, 0x02,         // Output (array)
    0xC0                // end collection

};
reportLength = sizeof(reportDescriptor);
return reportDescriptor;
}
```

Given input length, output length are both pass via the struct I showed above.

I'm currently running the code, and plugged the USB port that is now supposed to be USBHID into my computer, and the device now shows up under device manager like this:

[image: Under Human Interface Devices]

I can see it's the device I programmed:
[image]

And windows states that the device failed to start.  Why is that?  What does the handshake process to have a valid device look like?  What could I be missing here?

I took it a step further and verified that other mbed examples worked.  One of them was for a USB-HID mouse, and it detects and functions as desired.

I'm setting this project up to send and receive custom reports to this device.

Comment: As far as I know, you will need some sort of a driver (registry entries) to make your device known to the windows kernel. For mouse, keyboard, they might already be there. Run regedit and have a look at the registry entries for other working devices and try to compare if anything is missing. You might need a .ini file for registering.